# Use CSS to move a WordPress widget into different area

Tags: html, css

I've got a site which is about to hit a traffic milestone. As we countdown to our millionth visitor, I thought it would be fun to move my stats widget from the right sidebar, and nest it in the corner of my site header element.

So far, I've managed to use this `CSS` to move the Widget out of the side menu... but I'm really struggling to figure out how to put this element into another div.

```
.bottomright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

This popped the widget out of the sidebar, and made it hover always in the corner.  Neat...

[image]

My goal though, is to move that widget into this spot

[image]

Following [this guide from the W3 Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_text_top_left), I've tried to nest the widget into the div I want it to go inside of (which is called `header.site-header`)

Here's the element I want it to go inside:

[image]

If I set it's position absolute and fiddle with sizing, I can shove it where I want it to go, but this doesn't look good for tablets or mobiles.

```
#blog-stats-2 {
position: absolute;
   top: 75px;
   right:5px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    z-index:5;
}
```

[image]

Is there any keyword I'm missing to nest this in the corner of the `site-header` div?

Comment: Ultimately it would be best to add a widget area in the header and place the widget there. Trying to move something from a sidebar to a header via CSS can be done but in a lot of instances will likely produced side effects. Especially when your site is responsive.

Comment: This is hosted WordPress, so I can't just add in a function or a custom Widget Area, which would be awesome :(  @MichaelCoker, If I add relative to site-header, how would I modify the css for the widget to push it into the header?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move your hit counter into the header HTML first before using `position: absolute;` otherwise it simply won't work. Try something like this.

*You'll need to work this into your HTML code.*

```html
<header class="site-header">

    <div id="blog-stats-2">

        <!-- code here -->

    </div>

</header>
```

*Then your CSS like this.*

```css
header.site-header {
  position: relative;
}

#blog-stats-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 123;
}
```

What that does is moves your hit counter into the header section and positions it absolutely to the bottom right of the header. Using `position: relative;` on a parent container and `position: absolute;` on a child element will make sure the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` attributes are relative to the parents location all the time.

For mobile you'll need to change this further using **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** to make sure it sits inside the header nicely.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  #blog-stats-2 {
    left: 10px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
  }

}
```